# How to do something similar to the useOnClickOutside functionality in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to use breakdown blocks, they don't necessarily have a text field, but they can open some content and I want to have an effect like `onBlur` in `TextInput`, usually I could achieve this effect (on the web) with the `useOnClickOutside` custom hook, but I don't know how is it possible to achieve this effect or something similar in react-native, can anyone advise on this?
I need this functionality to collapse this block if the user clicks elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, which will help me create popovers of any style without being tied to any library, I found my solution, I studied the work of the [react-native-element-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-element-dropdown) code, I think that since this library is supplied under the MIT license, I can explain the rethinking of them code

The first thing is to create a hook that will determine the placement of the popover:

```js
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react'
import { Dimensions, I18nManager, StatusBar, View } from 'react-native'

export type PositionType = {
  width: number
  top: number
  bottom: number
  left: number
  height: number
}

const statusBarHeight: number = StatusBar.currentHeight || 0

const usePosition = (ref: React.RefObject<View>) => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState<PositionType>({ width: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, height: 0 })

  const { width: W, height: H } = Dimensions.get('window')

  const onLayout = useCallback(() => {
    if (ref?.current) {
      ref.current.measureInWindow((pageX, pageY, width, height) => {
        const top = height + pageY
        const bottom = H - top + height
        const left = I18nManager.isRTL ? W - width - pageX : pageX

        setPosition({
          width: Math.floor(width),
          top: Math.floor(top + statusBarHeight),
          bottom: Math.floor(bottom - statusBarHeight),
          left: Math.floor(left),
          height: Math.floor(height),
        })
      })
    }
  }, [H, W])

  return { position, onLayout }
}

export default usePosition
```

The approach through the hook is necessary to correctly work out the miscalculation, since if you transfer this layout to the component of the popover itself, for example, the `useEffect` hook, it will not be the correct position, since the layout is calculated after the execution of all internal `useEffects` (Although I may be wrong)

After that, we create a component that will be a wrapper for the popover and interact with the hook:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Modal, View, ViewProps } from 'react-native'
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native'
import { PositionType } from './usePosition'

export type DropdownProps = React.PropsWithChildren & {
  position: PositionType
  isOpen: boolean
  onClose: () => void
  isWidthFromPosition?: boolean
  style?: ViewProps['style']
}

const Dropdown: React.FC<DropdownProps> = ({
  position,
  isOpen,
  onClose,
  children,
  style,
  isWidthFromPosition = false,
}): JSX.Element => {
  const { width, top, left } = position

  return (
    <Modal
      transparent
      statusBarTranslucent
      visible={isOpen}
      supportedOrientations={['landscape', 'portrait']}
      onRequestClose={onClose}
    >
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onClose}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View
            style={[
              {
                position: 'absolute',
                left,
                top,
              },
              // If you need the width to be the same as the element to which the popover is attached 
              isWidthFromPosition ? { width } : undefined,
              style,
            ]}
          >
            {children}
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </Modal>
  )
}

export default Dropdown
```

and all this now you can display a popover with the `useOnClickOutside' effect to close it when clicking outside the popover itself, YES THERE IS A NUANCE - since this is an invisible modal window, when you click on some other interaction effect, the modal window will first be closed, and only then will it be possible click on another element, but for me it is acceptable and I think it is an acceptable logic for such a function, maybe in the future it will be possible to invent something better.

Used:

```js
...
const YourComponent = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
  const ref = useRef<View>(null)
  const { position, onLayout } = usePosition(ref)

  const handleFocus = () => setIsOpen(true)
  const handleBlur = () => setIsOpen(false)

  return (
    <View ref={ref} onLayout={onLayout}>
       <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={handleFocus}>
         <View style={{ width: 40, height: 40, backgroudnColor: 'red' }} />
       </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
       <Dropdown position={position} isOpen={isFocus} onClose={handleBlur}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => console.log('Hi, I am POPOVER')}>
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'pink' }}>
            <Text>Hi, I am POPOVER</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </Dropdown>
    <View>
  )
}
...
```

This is approximately the result already with my use:
[image]